# dax - counting rows between dates

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table like

```
Account   Open        Close
1         01/01/2018  01/01/2019
2         01/01/2018  01/01/2020
3         01/01/2019  01/01/2021
4         01/01/2021  
5         01/01/2019  01/01/2020
```

I'm interested in counting the number of accounts that are still active at the end of each year:

```
Year  Count
2018   2
2019   3
2020   1
2021   1
```

I'm not sure if this can be derived from the `Account` table itself, so I created a date table with dates spanning many years. I added a column like

`active_accounts = countrows ( Accounts, FILTER ( Accounts[Open] >= Date_table[Date] && Date_table[Date] < Accounts[Close]`

The formula seemed to be working as an added column but took extremely long to calculate as the date table contains many dates. So I tried to use the formula as a DAX measure, but it seems to have trouble comparing columns between more than one table:

`a single value for column 'Date' in table 'date_table' can't be determined. This can happen when a measure refers to a column containing many values without specifying aggregation`

What's the simplest way to accomplish counting the number of active accounts in a particular year? Can this be done without a date table?

edit: enclosing `date_table[date]` with `min()` and `max()` makes the measure valid, but the figures are not right.
-further research indicates this might require `CROSSJOIN()`

edit: it looks like this can be accomplished by creating a cartesian product b/w the `date_table` and `Account` by `FILTERING` on where `Date_table.Date` is greater than `Open` but less than `Close`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already created a Calendar table and you can achieve the end goal with the following measure

```
_mX:= 
VAR _1 =
    GENERATEALL (
        'fact',
        DATESBETWEEN ( 'Calendar'[Calendar_Date], 'fact'[Open], 'fact'[Close]-1 )
    )
VAR _2 =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        _1,
        "Calendar_Year",
            CALCULATE (
                MAXX (
                    FILTER ( 'Calendar', 'Calendar'[Calendar_Date] = [Calendar_Date] ),
                    'Calendar'[Calendar_Year]
                ) + 0
            )
    )
VAR _3 =
    SUMMARIZE ( _2, [Calendar_Year], [Account] ) 
VAR _4 =
    GROUPBY ( _3, [Calendar_Year], "count", COUNTX ( CURRENTGROUP (), [Account] ) ) 
VAR _5 =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        'Calendar',
        "ct",
            CALCULATE (
                MAXX (
                    FILTER ( _4, [Calendar_Year] = MAX ( 'Calendar'[Calendar_Year] ) ),
                    [count]
                )
            )
    )
RETURN
    MAXX ( _5, [ct] )
```

[image: Solution]

The measure is depended upon a calendar table with minimum columns like following and calendar has no relationship to fact

```
| Calendar_Date | Calendar_Year |
|---------------|---------------|
| 1/1/2018      | 2018          |
```